# How to set connection timeout while creating JDBC SQL Driver connection(JAVA)?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

It it is taking 60 minutes for a connection to establish. How do I resolve?

Tried

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://" + host + ":" + port + ";databaseName=" + database
                    + ";", uname, passwd+ "");
```

Thanks

Comment: Why have you tagged this question with mysql when your connection string is SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the specific JDBC driver.

You might want to look here:

http://www.cubrid.org/blog/dev-platform/understanding-jdbc-internals-and-timeout-configuration/